# Styled-Components Text or Paragraphs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Is it possible to style Text or Paragraphs with styled-components? If yes, how can I pass text into the component?

For example, I had this Footer component:

```
const Footer = () => (
  <footer className="site-footer">
    <p className="text"> HELLO</p>
    <Copyright
      link={'https://hotmail.com'}
      text={'HELOO'}></Copyright>
  </footer>
);

export default Footer;
```

I wanted to switch from global classes to css in js, which is why I thought of using styled-components. Now I tried this:

```
export const StyledText = styled.text`
    text: Hellooo
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
`
```

But if I comment out the paragraph and use StyledText component, nothing shows up. If I try passing `Styled Component text={'HELLO'}` my app crashes. How can I convert my footer in such a way that it uses styled-components?

Comment: Instead of `.text`, you are looking for `styled.p` which is the HTML element you want to render

Comment: Oops, I thought ```.p```gave an error. Nevertheless, what's the right way to pass the text into it? And what's ```styled.text```for then? @Agney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`styled-components` just deals with the styles of a component and not the content. All `children` will be preserved, so you can do something like this:

```
// JSX
<StyledText>Hello</StyledText>

// StyledText.js
export default styled.p`
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update your component to look like this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledText = styled.p`
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
`;

export default function Footer({text}){
  return   <footer className="site-footer">
    <StyledText>{text}</StyledText>
    <Copyright
      link={'https://hotmail.com'}
      text={text}/>
  </footer>;
}
```

You will be able to call your `Footer` component like:

```
<Footer text="HELLO"/>
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can style every `html` element and every custom component as long its passes `className`.

This example covers pretty much the basic API:

```
const Text = styled.p`
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
`;

const Copyright = ({ className, link, text }) => (
  <div className={className}>
    <Text>{link}</Text>
    <Text>{text}</Text>
  </div>
);

const StyledCopyright = styled(Copyright)`
  border: 1px black solid;
  ${Text} {
    color: palevioletred;
  }
`;

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <footer>
      <Text>HELLO</Text>
      <Copyright link="https://hotmail.com" text="World" />
      <StyledCopyright link="https://hotmail.com" text="World" />
    </footer>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit serene-hugle-qgsfy]